# Mixing cloth types in blender 2.8

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

Is it possible to link together meshes with different cloth physics properties? For example, think of a mesh with silk properties to act as a liner in a leather cloak or ribbon streamers 'sewed' to, say, denim?

Comment: Yes, why not? Did you tried to make something like this and it didn't worked?

Comment: Yes, it didn't.
Cloth properties transferred, rather than remaining discreet.
I have since located some comments suggesting use of empties as an intermediate step and adding hooks, but I haven't got the meshes to join yet.

Comment: Soooo @cgsav, would you care to outline the technique for posterity?